# EF Core with SQL Server: bulk load data was expected but not sent

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Our project has recently been facing an uncommon error in queries when using SQL Server database. Unfortunately, the error is not limited to a specific query and I cannot guess the reason. Up to now, it has happened in queries containing `Any`, `Single`, or `First`. It seems that it is related to something inside EF Core, but as it was not happening before I don't think this can be an EF bug.

Where is this error coming from? What are the solutions? I would appreciate your helps to identify the cause.

Here's an example stack trace:

```
[08:54:28 INF] Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'MyDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0' with options: MigrationsAssembly=MyProject.Migrations.SqlServer
[08:54:28 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [w].[Id], [w].[CreatedAt], [w].[Model]
FROM [Workflows] AS [w]
WHERE [w].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
[08:54:28 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MyProject.MyDbContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Bulk load data was expected but not sent. The batch will be terminated.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:84a2b4c4-0f92-4ac3-aace-4267617d8b98
Error Number:4022,State:1,Class:16
```

Comment: Do you have any BulkCopy code? Maybe you have multithreading issue?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv We don't directly perform any SQL and all the job is done by EF. Can you explain the multithreading issue? Do you mean using the context by multiple threads or possible concurrent queries to the database?

Comment: Job can be done by some extension also, not just pure EF Core . Yes, I mean using the same DbContext in concurrent threads.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the concurrency issue more deeply.